# Trouble With Nested Dicts

Tags: python

I have a simple nested dict to indicate a graph with nodes, vertices, and edge weights in the form dict:

`{node: {vertex: weight, ... } ...}`.

Here is how I create it:

```
with open(file) as f:
        __, __1 = next(f).split()
        for line in f:
            tail, head, weight = line.split()
                g1[tail] = {}
                g1[tail][head] = int(weight)
```

This code gives me the dict I want. However, when I run more code that creates a similar nested dict as well as accesses this dict, I run into an error. Here is the code:

```
nodes = g1.keys()
distance = {}

    for n in nodes:
        distance[n] = {}
    for k in nodes:
        distance[n][k] = graph[n][k]
```

Somewhere in here, this error crops up:

```
distance[n][k] = graph[n][k]
KeyError: '344'
```

indicating that I haven't yet created a key for '344,' which is what this code is trying to do. I thought by initializing each node n to a dict, I could then create an entry for distance[n][k]. I've tried using default dicts -- the result is the same. Why?

Comment: Did you try changing all initializations to `{}` by `dict()`?

Comment: Using literal syntax `{}` is appropriate, use of the `dict` builtin is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for n in nodes:
    distance[n] = {}
```

After this `for-loop` completes,  `n` is equal to the last value in `nodes`.

There is no guarantee that for every `k` in `nodes`, `graph[n][k]` exists:

```
for k in nodes:
    distance[n][k] = graph[n][k]
```

The `nodes` are all tails, not heads. So `k` is iterating over tails. Yet `graph[n][k]` is placing `k` in the position expected for a head.

The tails and the heads are not necessarily interchangeable, and the last tail, `n`, may not be connected to every other tail, `k`.

---

If you are trying to make `distance` a copy of `graph`, then use

```
import copy
distance = copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates not that you can't assign to `distance[n][k]`, but that there is no `344` in `graph[n]`.